# file_get_contents doesn't work if file has apostrophe in it

Tags: php, file-get-contents, apostrophe

Currently I am trying to retrieve a file that is located in a zip file which has an apostrophe in it. To achieve this I use the following code:

```
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$print = $_POST['print'];
$weborder = $_POST['weborder'];

$url = urlencode($filename);

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename='.$filename);

$pdf = file_get_contents('zip://z:/Backup/'.$print.'/'.$weborder.'.zip#'.$url.'');

echo $pdf;
```

Somehow this only works on files that don't have a special character in them. I tried to decode the filename to UTF-8 but that didn't help either.

So I was wondering if there is a way to open the files with special characters in the name.

Comment: You need to escape the filename: [addslashes()](http://php.net/addslashes)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Do I escape it in here?: $pdf = file_get_contents('zip://z:/Backup/'.$print.'/'.$weborder.'.zip#'.$url.'');

Comment: @Quartermain In `$filename = $_POST['filename'];`

Comment: First you should definitely make some checking and cleaning of all your variables coming from `$_POST` and second - yes try to `urlencode` the address before passing it to `file_get_contents`

Comment: All of the variables that are coming in from the $_POST are checked.  I tried urlencoding the filename but it still didn't  work. If I echo the filename on the page it shows the correct format with the apostrophe.

Comment: @Quartermain comment out the `header()` lines temporarily, make sure you're reporting/displaying errors, and could we see the full filename string (e.g. `var_dump('zip://....');`)?

Comment: This is error message I get when I comment out the header part: Warning: file_get_contents(zip://z:/Backup/luik/WEB0000049870.zip#13067-AP-03 A - Situation projetée.pdf) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: operation failed

Comment: It's not urlencoded...

Comment: No, that one has only the addslashes in it. The error message I get when I urlencode the filename is as follows:Warning: file_get_contents(zip://z:/Backup/luik/WEB0000049870.zip#13067-AP-03+A+-+Situation+projet%C3%A9e.pdf) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: operation failed in

Comment: odd #-mark after "zip"

Comment: That # is used to open the PDF since it is in a zip file.

Comment: The weird part is that all other files without a special character in them are opened without any problem.

Comment: @Quartermain, can you please give examples of working strings too?

Comment: mean you apostrophe `'` or some unicode like `Ć`

Comment: check disabled the magic_quotes feature. set proper locale with `setlocale`. I'd not to use urlencode on filesystem path.

Comment: What kind of server? Apache or IIS?

Comment: @Quartermain Been looking around for solutions. Can you try to open this please: `$file = "zip://z:/Backup/luik/WEB0000049870.zip#" . utf8_encode("13067-AP-03 A - Situation projetée.pdf");` but use `file_get_contents($file);`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75832/discussion-on-question-by-quartermain-file-get-contents-doesnt-work-if-file-has).

Comment: @Drakes, I'll try it out right now!

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, apologies, however the OP hasn't enough rep at the moment for a chat, or so I believe. (Apologies, and thank you for moving the chat)

Comment: @Drakes Yes, typically that is true but since I moved the comments the OP should be able to take part.